# Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ContactService: (?)

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have such kind of error after test use the karma+jsamine.
Service: ContactService should return available languages FAILED
        Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ContactService: (?).
I don't konw what lead to this.

```html
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
const CONTACT_URL = "./pages/contacts.json"

export class ContactService{
  constructor(private http:Http) { }
  public getContactById(id: number) {
    // return this.get(CONTACT_URL, { id: id });
  }
  get(){
    return this.http.get(CONTACT_URL).map(response => response.json())
  }
 }
```

```html
import {inject,TestBed,async} from "@angular/core/testing";
import {ContactService} from "./ContactService.component"
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";

describe('Service: ContactService', () => {
  let service;

  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports:[HttpModule],
    providers: [ ContactService ]
  }));

  beforeEach(inject([ContactService], s => {
    service = s;
  }));

  it('should return available languages',async(() => {
    service.get().subscribe(x=> {
      expect(x).toContain('en');
      expect(x).toContain('es');
      expect(x).toContain('fr');
      expect(x.length).toEqual(3);
    });

  }));
});
```

following is my code.

Comment: Try `Injectable` or `@Inject(Http)` and check your tsconfig

Answer (score 4):

Change this

```
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
const CONTACT_URL = "./pages/contacts.json"

export class ContactService
```

To

```
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
const CONTACT_URL = "./pages/contacts.json"

@Injectable()
export class ContactService
```